# GMT uncaughtException: Cannot read property 'send' of undefined Node js

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, api, response

My controller gets the response value but when i try to send the response, it throws error. The console.log of data gives the json value.

> GMT uncaughtException: Cannot read property 'send' of undefined

```
export const countController = {  
    countFetch: async (req, res) => {   
        await count((data, res) => {   
            res.send(data);
        })
    }
}
```

Please advise on where i did wrong. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the code snippet like below it will work

```js
export const countController = {  
    countFetch: async (req, res) => {   
        await count((data, countRes) => {   
            res.send(data);
        })
    }
}
```

You have defined `res` variable twice. So reference to express res object is lost.